# show mysql results in php just if a row=with

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, filter

I have this code and i want to show the results just if the row "SOLVED" = 1 . If i put the statement where solved='1' my filters doesn't work anymore are show all the results . 
I am new in php and a little help will pe appreciated .

```html
<?php
###########################################################
/*
GuestBook Script
Copyright (C) 2012 StivaSoft ltd. All rights Reserved.


This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
(at your option) any later version.

This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
GNU General Public License for more details.

You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
along with this program.  If not, see http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.html.

For further information visit:
http://www.phpjabbers.com/
info@phpjabbers.com

Version:  1.0
Released: 2012-03-18
*/
###########################################################

error_reporting(1);
include("config.php");
$SETTINGS["data_table"]='problems'; // this is the default database name that we used



?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

</head>


<body>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
@import url("style.css");
-->
</style>

<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="list-problems-active.php">
<label for="from">From</label>
<input name="from" type="text" id="from" size="10" value="<?php echo $_REQUEST["date"]; ?>" />
<label for="to">to</label>
<input name="to" type="text" id="to" size="10" value="<?php echo $_REQUEST["to"]; ?>"/>
 <label>Name or Email:</label>
<input type="text" name="string" id="string" value="<?php echo stripcslashes($_REQUEST["string"]); ?>" />
<label>Location</label>
<select name="location">
<option value="">--</option>
<?php
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$SETTINGS["data_table"]." GROUP BY location ORDER BY location ";
 $sql_result = mysql_query ($sql, $connection ) or die ('request "Could not execute SQL query" '.$sql);
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_result)) {
  echo "<option value='".$row["location"]."'".($row["location"]==$_REQUEST["location"] ? " selected" : "").">".$row["location"]."</option>";
 }
?>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Filter" />
  </label>
  <a href="list-problems-active.php"> 
  reset</a>
</form>
<br /><br />
<table id="newspaper-b" summary="2007 Major IT Companies' Profit">
  
      <thead>
     <tr>
         <th scope="col">Id</th>
            <th scope="col">Location</th>
            <th scope="col">Manager</th>
            <th scope="col">Problem Info</th>
   <th scope="col">Date</th>
   <th scope="col">Author</th>
   <th scope="col">Solved</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
<?php
if ($_REQUEST["string"]<>'') {
 $search_string = " AND (location LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["string"])."%' OR problem LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["string"])."%')"; 
}
if ($_REQUEST["location"]<>'') {
 $search_city = " AND location='".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["location"])."'"; 
}

if ($_REQUEST["from"]<>'' and $_REQUEST["to"]<>'') {
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$SETTINGS["data_table"]." WHERE from_date >= '".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["from"])."' AND to_date <= '".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["to"])."'".$search_string.$search_city;
} else if ($_REQUEST["from"]<>'') {
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$SETTINGS["data_table"]." WHERE from_date >= '".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["from"])."'".$search_string.$search_city;
} else if ($_REQUEST["to"]<>'') {
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$SETTINGS["data_table"]." WHERE to_date <= '".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["to"])."'".$search_string.$search_city;
} else {
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$SETTINGS["data_table"]." WHERE id>0".$search_string.$search_city;
}

//$sql_result = mysql_query ("select Id, location, manager, problem, date, author from problems where solved=0 ORDER BY date desc") or die ('request "Could not execute SQL query" '.$sql);
$sql_result = mysql_query ($sql, $connection ) or die ('request "Could not execute SQL query" '.$sql);
//$sql_result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM problems WHERE solved='0'");
if (mysql_num_rows($sql_result)>0) {
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_result)) {
  
  
?>


  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $row["Id"]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row["location"]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row["manager"]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row["problem"]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row["date"]; ?></td>
 <td><?php echo $row["author"]; ?></td>
 <td><?php echo "<a href='set-as-solved.php?Id=" . $row['Id'] . "'> <img src='check.png" . $last_file[0] . "' alt='error'> " ?></td>
  
  </tr>
<?php
 }
} else {
?>
<tr><td colspan="5">No results found.</td>
<?php 
}
?>
</table>


<script>
 $(function() {
  var dates = $( "#from, #to" ).datepicker({
   defaultDate: "+1w",
   changeMonth: true,
   numberOfMonths: 2,
   dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
   onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
    var option = this.id == "from" ? "minDate" : "maxDate",
     instance = $( this ).data( "datepicker" ),
     date = $.datepicker.parseDate(
      instance.settings.dateFormat ||
      $.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat,
      selectedDate, instance.settings );
    dates.not( this ).datepicker( "option", option, date );
   }
  });
 });
 </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm no PHP coder, but this strikes me as a really clumsy way to build a query. Further, I think there's a tendency here to avoid questions that involve PHP's long-since deprecated mysql_ API

Comment: you have not added anything in the where section. it is suppose to retrieve all rows

Comment: And where i am supposed to add that where section in order form filters to still work ?